# HTML not rendering correctly after installing Wordpress on Ubuntu

Tags: apache2, php, wordpress

I have followed the tutorial on ubuntu.com to install Wordpress on a fresh Ubuntu installation. Everything seemed to work correctly until I browsed to the wp startup page. The startup page did not display correctly. Furthermore subsequent startup pages did not diplay correctly.

The startup page displays like this:
Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?
[image: WP Startup Page]

Comment: This looks like a .htaccess error where the site can't find the asset files including CSS and images. I would suggest you redo step 3 then try again. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#3-configure-apache-for-wordpress

Comment: Many thanks. I have worked out what was happening. The web server on a ubuntu machine was connected to the internet via a reverse proxy on a Synology NAS. The comms between the reverse proxy and the internet was https whereas the comms between the web server and the reverse proxy was http. Consequently CSS and images were getting filtered out. I am now using https between the web server and the reverse proxy, and all is well.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked out what was happening. The web server on a ubuntu machine was connected to the internet via a reverse proxy on a Synology NAS. The comms between the reverse proxy and the internet was https whereas the comms between the web server and the reverse proxy was http. Consequently CSS and images were getting filtered out. I am now using https between the web server and the reverse proxy, and all is well